# Is there a way of getting Katalon Studio to authenticate with AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito, katalon-studio

I'm writing some API tests using Katalon Studio which test an AWS API Gateway secured with AWS Cognito. If I provide the JWT in the authentication header, the tests passes as expected. I'm struggling to work out how I should be requesting the JWT based on supplied credentials as part of the test. Is there an easy way I'm missing?

Comment: I am not familiar with Katalon Studio, but I have done quite a bit of work with Amazon Cognito during my time at AWS. Have you looked into the vanilla InitiateAuth/AdminInitiateAuth API calls yet?